# Protect the git repository

Tags: git, repository

I'm having git repository in my Dropbox. After I updated or modified the code in my local repository I will push the local repository to Dropbox's repository.

I need to protect the repository from cloning by password or any other mean. Because i'm feeling that Dropbox team can see my git repository and able to clone.
Is it possible to protect the git repository?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use dropbox for this? There are alternatives (free, too) that will allow you to protect your repo by making it private (bitbucket for example)

Comment: @TimCastelijns His repo is private on Dropbox, he thinks that the company itself is going to look at whats inside his repository. Not another 3rd party. OP if you want this kind of security you should host your own server and add your own users. Otherwise you're trusting your data to a 3rd party, private or not and theres no way around that.

Comment: Using DropBox for anything other than Git bundles will eventually corrupt your repository. Don't borrow trouble.

Comment: @PeterFoti Thanks for your information.I need to keep my project online and safe.Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar im not sure in what way its not safe now. Take whatever it is that you think is not safe about Dropbox, and then setup your own server without it.